Can I disable default Marker Context (NoMarker) passed implicitly when using play.api.Logger and require a different MarkerContext is always provided?
I am trying to add a unique request id to logs for each request that is made to a rest api. For that I want to pass implicitly a MarkerContext to each logger method called. Currently the NoMarker context is provided by default. Can I turn this off so that I get a compilation error when trying to log without providing an implicit MarkerContext to the method.
My current approach is:
Define a MarkerContextWrapper:
class MarkerContextWrapper(markerContext: MarkerContext) {
  def getMarkerContext: MarkerContext = markerContext
}

Define MarkerLogger:
class MarkerLogger(clazz: Class[_]){

  private val logger = Logger(clazz)

  def debug(message: => String)(implicit markerContextWrapper: MarkerContextWrapper): Unit = {
    logger.debug(message)(markerContextWrapper.getMarkerContext)
  }

  def debug(message: => String, error: => Throwable)(implicit markerContextWrapper: MarkerContextWrapper): Unit = {
    logger.debug(message, error)(markerContextWrapper.getMarkerContext)
  }

 ....
 ....

}

In the each method use the MarkerLogger instead of the play.api.Logger
private val logger = Logger(this.getClass)
private val logger = MarkerLogger(this.getClass)
Add (implicit markerContextWrapper: MarkerContextWrapper) to every method that logs something.
Instantiate a new MarkerContext wrapper inside my Custom Controller actions:
 case class DeviceRequest[A](
     device:  Device,
     request: Request[A],
     markerContextWrapper: MarkerContextWrapper
 ) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

object DeviceAction extends ActionBuilder[DeviceRequest, AnyContent] {

   private val logger = MarkerLogger(this.getClass)

   override def executionContext = ec

   override def parser = p

   override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (DeviceRequest[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
      implicit val markerContextWrapper = requestHeaderToMarkerContextWrapper(request)

      ....
      ....

      block(DeviceRequest(device, request, markerContextWrapper))
}

This approach doesn't stop anyone form still using the Logger and not the wrapper in which case the default NoMarker might be passed. Is there a way to disable this and make the developer have to provide the MarkerContext every time a Logger method is used?
Or is there a completely different approach to provide a unique request id accross multiple threads, without so much refactoring?

These guys implemented something similar but it is for htt4s: https://github.com/softwaremill/bootzooka/blob/master/backend/src/main/scala/com/softwaremill/bootzooka/logging/FLogging.scala . Maybe you can find some answers from their solution.
